# Using pattern recognition matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, pattern-recognition

I used the nprtool and the breast cancer dataset to generate a sample neural network for learning purposes. The following code was generated (and slightly modified) by the matlab nprtool (pattern recognition tool). However this is only to train the network, now what I require is to have an input entered (the feature values and there are currently 9 feature values in the dataset) and have the most likeliest output given to me. Does anyone know how this is done or can anyone point me in the right direction. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
% Create Network
numHiddenNeurons = 20;  % Adjust as desired
net = newpr(cancerInputs,cancerTargets,numHiddenNeurons);
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;  % Adjust as desired
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;  % Adjust as desired
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;  % Adjust as desired

% Train and Apply Network
[net,tr] = train(net,cancerInputs,cancerTargets);
outputs = sim(net,cancerInputs);

% Plot
plotperf(tr)
plotconfusion(cancerTargets,outputs)
```

Regards,
Milinda

Comment: 'outputs = sim(net,cancerInputs);' line is what you want. Change the 'cancerInputs' to your test set.